# kubectl use config for authentication

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, kubectl, kubeconfig

I'm creating a pipeline to deploy some application in kubernetes.

I've been given the authentication credentials as a yaml file similar to the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tL******0tLS0t
    server: https://api.whatever.com
  name: gs-name-clientcert
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: gs-name-clientcert
    user: gs-name-clientcert-user
  name: gs-name-clientcert
current-context: gs-name-clientcert
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: gs-name-clientcert-user
  user:
    client-certificate-data: LS************RS0tLS0t
    client-key-data: LS0tL***********tLQ==
```

How can I tell kubectl to use that config file when I use the apply command?
Thanks.

Comment: There are multiple ways, **1st** `export KUBECONFIG=/path/to/yaml`, **2nd**, place the yaml in the default directory, Eg, `~/.kube/config`, **3rd**, use `--kubeconfig /path/to/yaml` flag while using `kubectl` commands

Comment: I tried --kubeconfig it says : `error: error loading config file "/var/cred-deployer.yaml": yaml: line 5: mapping values are not allowed in this context`

Comment: the content of `/var/cred-deployer.yaml` is same as the one provided in the question?

Comment: ok I solved, the indentation was wrong. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @DeejonZ Since your issue is resolved can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it for better community reach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**kubeconfig file path:**

The config modifies kubeconfig files using subcommands like “kubectl config set current-context my-context”
The loading order follows these rules:

1. If the –kubeconfig flag is set, then only that file is loaded. The flag may only be set once and no merging takes place.
2. If the $KUBECONFIG environment variable is set, then it uses a list of paths (normal path delimiting rules for your system). These paths are merged together. When a value is modified, it is modified in the file that defines the stanza. When a value is created, it is created in the first file that exists. If no files in the chain exist, it creates the last file in the list.
3. Otherwise, ${HOME}/.kube/config is used and no merging takes place.

   kubectl config SUBCOMMAND

   Options

   --kubeconfig="": use a particular kubeconfig file

For more information refer to the command [kubectl config](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config/) and also follow the path [config file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/).

**Also check the indentation of your config file:**

- If you are using TAB for indentation or any other purpose. Only use SPACE characters.
- To find indentation errors use monospaced fonts to view and edit YAML.

For more information about indentation refer to [Indentation to YAML](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/yaml/yaml_indentation_and_separation.htm#:%7E:text=YAML%20in%20detail.-,Indentation%20of%20YAML,-YAML%20does%20not)